# How do I resolve the 404 error that I'm getting from the Github API?

Tags: python, api, github, http-status-code-404, github-api

I'm trying to pull the contributor stats from a public github repo. I followed every step mentioned in their [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/metrics/statistics?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-last-year-of-commit-activity) but I keep getting a 404 error. Does someone happen to know what the issue is?

This is my python script:

```
import requests
import json


url = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/stats/contributors"

url = url.format(OWNER="cosmos", REPO="ibc-go")

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <MY-TOKEN>",
    "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
print(r.status_code)
#print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/stats/contributors"
```

to

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/stats/contributors"
```

as `url.format` ir `str.format` is not replacing the `OWNER` AND `REPO` in the `url` string

Comment: ah my b. thank you! works now

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I made @sahasrara62's change and also commented out the "Authorization..." line (apparently it's not needed for this endpoint), the result looks like this:

`[{'total': 1, 'weeks': [{'w': 1612656000, 'a': 0, 'd': 0, 'c': 0}, ....`